# Using negative CSS Custom Properties

Tags: css, css-variables

In preprocessors, like SASS, you can use negative values like:

```
$margin-md: 10px;

.class {
  margin-bottom: -$margin-md;
}
```

How do I do this using custom properties?

```
// This doesn't work
.class {
  margin-bottom: -var(--margin-md);
}
```

Answer (score 256, accepted):

As of this posting, March 2018, the only way to use negative custom properties is by multiplying it by `-1` with the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function.

```css
/* Vanilla CSS */


/* Using multiplication */
.class {
    margin-bottom: calc(var(--margin-md) * -1);
}

/* Using Subtraction (from @GibsonFX comment) */
.class {
    margin-bottom: calc(0 - var(--margin-md));
}
```

Subtraction works for the units that does not support multiplication

Comment: It's not the only way... you can subtract it from 0px aswell, i.e. margin-bottom: calc( 0px - var(--myvalue) ); While it's fundimentally identical in and of itself, since units like vh and vw don't allow multiplication or devision by other units, so in some rare cases the existence of a multiplication in the same may cause problems, although I'm only guessing, but why take the chance, or have an alternative on the off chance it does?